# Is there a way to get a unique value per dupli group instance?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, objects, dupli-groups

Given a number of dupligroups, is there a way to get a unique random value for each one in a cycles shader?

Using the object info node won't work, as each instance consists of multiple objects. I'd like the value to be the same for all objects in the group (in this example, the pedestals ought to be the same as the corresponding Suzanne).

[image]

Here's a demo file:

[image]

If possible, I'd like to do this without joining objects or de-instantiating the dupligroups.

Comment: I have run into this issue before, never found a solution. Was wondering again today if a solution exists. Sounds like a good feature request.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Particles as host for DupliGroup**

Thus we can use cool feature of mesh-emitter called `From Dupli`. This means duplis will inherit location of corresponding space on UV map.

- Create emitter mesh and unwrap all faces of emitter as separate islands (avoid overlapping in order to have unique values)
- Add PS system, so amount of particles is equal to face count (disable
  *emit random*, *even distribution* and set *particle/face* ratio to 1)
- Choose `Whole group` as source for duplicating

[image]

[image]